# HTTPRIO AfterExecute problem

Tags: delphi

I suppose that after the HTTPRio component receives the data, it parses the data. I'm saying this because after the program leaves the AfterExecute procedure it takes ages before continuing to the next line of code.

Want I want is to clear the data that has arrived on the AfterExecute procedure. Is this possible?

```
procedure TEventHandlers.thhoptAfterExecute(const MethodName: string;
  SOAPResponse: TStream);
var
  fs : TFileStream;
begin
  fs := TFileStream.Create('F:\Lixosam\LixoSMS'+
        IntToStr(ThCampanha),
            fmCreate, fmShareDenyNone);
  SOAPResponse.Position := 0;
  fs.CopyFrom(SOAPResponse, SOAPResponse.Size);
  fs.Free;
end;
```

How can I clear the data so the component doesn't have to do any parsing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write whatever you want into the SOAPResponse. You can clear it, edit it, whatever. If a completely empty response causes trouble with deserialization (complaints about "document must have top-level element, at line 0"), you could stick in a "skeleton" response that provides minimal structure.  If you edit the response, you should set the size accordingly.
Here is some code that I have:

```
var
  sl : TStringList;

begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SOAPResponse.Position := 0;
    sl.LoadFromStream(SOAPResponse);    // Load the response into a stringlist so we can work on it.

    // some manipulation to the lines in sl occur here, such as stringreplaces and such.


    // Now write out edits back out to the stream.
    SOAPResponse.Position := 0;            // Now overwrite the crappy response with our good one.
    SOAPResponse.size := length(sl.Text);  // Important - set new length before saving.  Otherwise, the old
    sl.SaveToStream(SOAPResponse);         // leftover crud is still there, at the end, and the XML will blow up on it.

  finally
    FreeAndNil(sl);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. That's want I wanted